# Unable to make bot reply in thread on Slack

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, slack

I have a single-tenant bot, built on `Bot.Builder 18.1` that is currently running in a Slack channel. My challenge is that I would like the bot to always reply in a thread, when possible, so:

- If already in a thread, reply in that thread
- If on a channel, create a new thread and reply there

As far as I understand, the way to achieve this is to set the property `thread_ts` to the value of the `ts` property. I can get this value, however all attempts to set `thread_ts` still only give me replies in the channel directly, and not in a new thread, as expected. My last failed attempt was setting it on the reply message:

```cs
string? thread_ts = null;
if (slackChannelData is not null)
{
   thread_ts = slackChannelData?.SlackMessage?._event?.ts;
}
reply.Conversation.Properties[nameof(thread_ts)] = thread_ts;
```

And yes, I do get the `ts` value out of that :)

I also attempted to use the Slack Adapter, however it fails for som authentication reasons, even though I've set it's required configuration values (`SlackBotToken`, `SlackVerificationToken` and `SlackClientSigningSecret`). I cannot get the Slack Adapter to get past the authentication. The slack adapter follows the latest example on GitHub, and targets the community.adapters.slack version 4.13.5

So my question is:
Does anyone know if it is possible to use the Bot Framework and a slack channel to reply in thread in Slack given my want above?

Comment: Hi Pedro, were you able to implement this somehow? I am also looking to do something similar in my upcoming project and want to know if it is possible.

Comment: I found a way to do this, please check my answer below. Hope it helps you or someone coming here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We can implement the following code in v4 to reply in a thread. [Here is the GitHub issue from where I got my answer](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3722)

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
    conversationReference.Conversation.Properties["thread_ts"] = turnContext.Activity.Id; // force the reference to go in a slack thread

    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Some reply"), cancellationToken);
}
```